# Can I install Backup Exec in a guest

Tags: backup, virtualization, backupexec

We want to have a single physical machine as host, having several guests. One of the backup solutions we're considering is using Backup Exec to backup to external disks or tape, having Backup Exec installed in one of the guests (and agents in the other guests, we're considering the V-ray edition). Is this possible? We do not want to use a separate backup server. With regards to resource use there should not be a problem since backups will take place at night.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes you can at least with the latest version.

I had a similar setup: BackupExec installed on a guest vm for backup all guest VMs on a single host to a nas and a tape. I wasn't enthusiastic about the performance thought.

I switched to veeam more straightforward if you have to backup VMs IMHO ( http://www.veeam.com/ )